# IIS Url rewrite not working for different domain

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

The below syntax for url rewrite is not working and says as 404

The sample pattern being tested is

```
<img src="/static-images/6895fddc-4873-4e86-bc69-a7de30d9b035newoptions.png"/>

 <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="static-images/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="https://imageserver.com/images/6895fddc-4873-4e86-bc69-a7de30d9b035newoptions.png" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />                
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: Mistake 3 https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score -1):

When redirecting to a different hostname you must use `type="Redirect"`.

You should [read about the different options for `type`](https://blogs.iis.net/owscott/url-rewrite-vs-redirect-what-s-the-difference#:%7E:text=IIS%20URL%20Rewrite%20has%20five%20different%20types%20of%20actions.&text=Simply%20put%2C%20a%20redirect%20is,it%27s%20fully%20processed%20by%20IIS.).